Running a 'for' loop for a sequence of numbers but I'm just getting a reprint with the range function
Online course presented this problem and I can't figure it out. What it's supposed to output is at the bottom.
def odd_numbers(maximum):

    return_string = "" # Initializes variable as a string

    # Complete the for loop with a range that includes all
    # odd numbers up to and including the "maximum" value.
    for :

        # Complete the body of the loop by appending the odd number
        # followed by a space to the "return_string" variable.


    # This .strip command will remove the final " " space
    # at the end of the "return_string".
    return return_string.strip()

print(odd_numbers(6))  # Should be 1 3 5
print(odd_numbers(10)) # Should be 1 3 5 7 9
print(odd_numbers(1))  # Should be 1
print(odd_numbers(3))  # Should be 1 3
print(odd_numbers(0))  # No numbers displayed

I tried this:
def odd_numbers(maximum):

    return_string = "" # Initializes variable as a string

    # Complete the for loop with a range that includes all
    # odd numbers up to and including the "maximum" value.
      for n in range(maximum):
            return range(1, n, 2)
        # Complete the body of the loop by appending the odd number
        # followed by a space to the "return_string" variable.
        return_string = ", "

    # This .strip command will remove the final " " space
    # at the end of the "return_string".
    return return_string.strip()

print(odd_numbers(6))  # Should be 1 3 5
print(odd_numbers(10)) # Should be 1 3 5 7 9
print(odd_numbers(1))  # Should be 1
print(odd_numbers(3))  # Should be 1 3
print(odd_numbers(0))  # No numbers displayed

It printed out this:
range(1, 0, 2)
range(1, 0, 2)
range(1, 0, 2)
range(1, 0, 2)

It works when I use the list function but that's not the form it should be in because I keep getting it wrong.

for n in range(maximum): return range(1, n, 2): all you're doing is returning the range on the first iteration of the loop, which will just print that range, and defeats the purpose of the loop. Look into the join method of strings, which will help you out a lot. Or, add numbers one at a time to the return_string, which seems to be how they want you to do it (but still look into join, since that's an incredibly useful function).

You are always unconditionally returning on the first loop iteration.
You want to append to return_string on each iteration instead.
   for n in range(maximum): 
       return_string += f"{n} "

But you only want to do that if the number is odd, and you need to have your range go to maximum plus one, because range is a tail-exclusive range.
   for n in range(maximum + 1): 
       if n % 2 == 1:
            return_string += f"{n} "

But as your use of range suggests you may suspect, this can be simpler.
   for n in range(1, maximum + 1, 2): 
       if n % 2 == 1:
            return_string += f"{n} "

You might even:
    return " ".join(str(n) for n in range(1, maximum + 1, 2))

